# Meaning of the expression "Whatever did we do?"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

"whatever did we do before XYZ thing existed?"

I heard this statement in a sentence and found it weird because I heard such a thing for the first time. Is it correct? What does it mean? And could you provide more examples of such sentences.

Later, I read a similar sentence in my book:

"What do these thunderstorms care if we have a king on board? "

Here, I understand that the speaker is trying to convey that the thunderstorms don't care if the king is on the ship. However I am not sure about the sentence especially the part "What do".

Answer (score 1):

In OP's first example, ***whatever*** is a more *emphatic* alternative to ***what***. It might still be a genuine enquiry, but that more emphatic form is more likely in a *rhetorical* question - with the speaker simply making the point that before XYZ was available, the (contextually-relevant) things we could do were severely restricted, or non-existent.

The second example is *definitely* rhetorical, with the speaker effectively just asserting that thunderstorms don't care who's on the ship. Which is blindingly obvious anyway, since non-sentient things like thunderstorms don't and can't care about *anything*. But exactly the same basic syntax applies to the extremely common rhetorical question...

> ***What do I care***?

...which never expects an answer, and always means ***I don't care at all***!

---

Note that ***what*** in the "care" examples is effectively an optional element that could be understood as meaning ***what amount***, or ***to what extent***. But exactly the same meanings could be expressed as straightforward rhetorical questions...

> ***Do these thunderstorms care if we have a king on board?***
>    ***Do I care***?

...where in both cases, the "answer" (which the speaker *isn't* expecting you to actually give) is ***No***!

Comment: Shouldn't the rhetorical question be: "What do I care for?"

Comment: No. A rhetorical question simply means a question where the "expected answer" should be obvious to both speaker and addressee, and thus doesn't need to be stated. Obviously you couldn't just start a conversation by going up to someone and saying ***What do I care**?*, because there has to be some prior context for it to refer to - whatever someone else has just told you or asked about, where you're effectively saying ***I don't care at all about that**!*